# How to disable JSCS validation for a specific part of code: Line must be at most 120 characters

Tags: javascript, jshint, jscs

In a specific part of my code I need to allow a string to longer that 120 characters.

I would like to disable for that line of code JSCS validation.

At the moment I get

```
JSCS: Line must be at most 120 characters
```

How to do it?

Comment: A quick search suggested [maximumLineLength](http://jscs.info/rules.html) would be the rule you want to change.

Comment: thanks, but it seems a global setting.... I need to make it works on a block of code only... not at global level.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution using this

```
//jscs:disable maximumLineLength
..long code here
//jscs:enable maximumLineLength
```

Ignore all rules at file level

```
//jscs:disable
```

Ignore specific rule at file level

```
//jscs:disable specificRule
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to disable globally in your `.jscsrc`, just add `"maximumLineLength": null` to it.